# Create a dynamically populated table from JSON API data

Tags: json, api, format

I'm trying to populate a table with the output of several API sources having extracted several identical variables from each source. So far I have most of the pieces I need worked out, such as how to retrieve the data, create the table and import the data in order to create the table using an existing framework. What I don't have is a means of formatting the API data to meet the framework's requirement such as..

Required format:

```
[
{id:1, name:"Billy Bob", age:"12", gender:"male", height:1, col:"red", dob:"", cheese:1},
{id:2, name:"Mary May", age:"1", gender:"female", height:2, col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982", cheese:true},
{id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", age:"42", height:0, col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982", cheese:"true"},
]
```

Create a table from the formatted data...

```
<div id="example-table"></div>

$("#example-table").tablear({
columns:[
    {title:"Name", field:"name"},
    {title:"Age", field:"age"},
    {title:"Gender", field:"gender"},
    {title:"Height", field:"height"},
    {title:"Favourite Color", field:"col"},
    {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob"},
    {title:"Cheese Preference", field:"cheese"},
],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you get json as response you need to parse the json and then play with that.

Example:

```
    if(response)
    {
     var myObj = parse.JSON(response) // this will give you the javascript 
           //object
    }
```

There is also another option of using jquery datatable using server side processing. This automatically creates a table for you.

[Jquery Datatable](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)